# Open quote is expected for attribute "executable" associated with an element type "exec"

Tags: ant, exec, executable

I am trying to execute a cmd  through my ant script. I am getting the following error:

> *build.xml:24: Open quote is expected for attribute "executable"
>   associated with an  element type  "exec".*

These are lines `22` through `27`. As you can see the line it is failing on - line `24` is the space above the *exec cmd*. I can't see where I forgot a quote and they look like the regular quotes to me. I checked the archives and I couldn't find anything similar.

```
<chmod file="/blddir/tools/gmake" perm="777"/>     
<echo message="Starting"/>    

<exec dir="/blddir/tools/" executable="gmake" vmlauncher="false" failonerror="true">
  <arg line="-s"/>     
</exec>
```

Comment: Could you post the complete build.xml file? Are you getting a "Ant build failed with error “SAXParseException: Open quote is expected for attribute...”?

Comment: I've just try your snippet - everything is ok. Are you sure that this is exactly the same code that you are running?

Answer (score 0):

The error message means your build script is not valid, because of missing open quote for attribute executable in the exec task, please recheck for something like :

```
<exec dir="/blddir/tools/" executable=gmake" vmlauncher="false" failonerror="true">
  <arg line="-s"/>     
</exec>
```

or

```
<exec dir="/blddir/tools/" executable=gmake vmlauncher="false" failonerror="true">
  <arg line="-s"/>     
</exec>
```

whereas the snippet you posted seems alright !?
Some editor - f.e. Eclipse Ant editor - should point to the syntax error

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same issue and it turned out that I copied the quotes into an editor from a website and the double quotation marks in the file were not the correct ones, they were the slated ones instead of the straight ones.

Opening the build.xml file in the NetBeans editor showed the problem clearly